# Azure DevOps - Build Linux Docker container using vmImage windows-latest

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-devops

We are using Azure DevOps build pipeline with `vmImage` `windows-latest` since we are developing on Windows machines.

Previously we have only used `App Services` with Operating System `Windows` and Publish set to `Code`.

Example:

[image]

We are now moving towards Docker Container running on Linux as `App Service` instead.

[image]

In order for us to have a cloud-agnostic architecture a Linux 64-bit container seems to be our best bet. Example from Google Cloud Run:

> Executables in the container image must be compiled for Linux 64-bit.
> Cloud Run specifically supports the Linux x86_64 ABI format.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#languages

There is no problem using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10 to publish our container image to our Azure Container registry and then linking this to our Azure App Service.

[image]

We are using `Azure App Service Container` as our publish template.

[image]

Following the guide for `Build and publish a Docker image to Azure Container Registry` works fine.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-docker-webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml#deploy-to-web-app-for-containers

However when accessing the app the following error is presented:

> :( Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can
> access the diagnostic resources.

[image]

Diagnose and solve problems -> Application Logs -> Platform Logs

I could see the following error:

[image]

> 2022-10-26T11:11:36.260Z ERROR - image operating system "windows"
> cannot be used on this platformErr: 0, Message: image operating system
> "windows" cannot be used on this platform 2022-10-26T11:11:36.634Z
> INFO  - Pull Image failed, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
> 2022-10-26T11:11:36.634Z ERROR - Pulling docker image
> projectcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/classificationapi:123 failed:
> 2022-10-26T11:11:37.604Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API
> responded with status code=InternalServerError,
> response={"message":"Get
> https://projectcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/v2/classificationapi/manifests/123:
> unauthorized: authentication required, visit
> https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}

It is really tricky because `image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform` is shown as a OK log and only `unauthorized: authentication required` is an Error log. Therefore I was stuck on this thinking it was an authentication error for several hours and I tried using the Release task `Azure Web App for Containers` instead etc.

I could verify that the `Azure App Service deploy` task worked fine however by using a tag that I had deployed from my local computer using Visual Studio that i knew worked instead of `$(Build.BuildId)`.

[image]

Azure DevOps state the following:

> Based on whether you're deploying a Linux or Windows app, make sure to
> respectively set vmImage to either `ubuntu-latest` or `windows-latest`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?view=azure-devops#build-a-linux-or-windows-image

Given that I can deploy a working container image on my Windows machine it should be possible I think.

Container registry:

Image built on my Windows machine with Visual Studio:

[image]

Image built on Azure DevOps:

[image]

There is no way to set Docker Platform in the Docker Task what I can see:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

> BuildKit currently isn't supported on Windows hosts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?view=azure-devops#how-do-i-set-the-buildkit-variable-for-my-docker-builds

https://www.docker.com/blog/faster-multi-platform-builds-dockerfile-cross-compilation-guide/

Comment: You can build Windows Docker container using `task: Docker@2` and setting `vmImage` to `windows-latest`.
You can build Windows container images using Microsoft-hosted Windows agents or Windows platform based self-hosted agents. All Microsoft-hosted Windows platform-based agents are shipped with the Moby engine and client needed for Docker builds.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops#what-agents-can-i-use-to-build-container-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `jobs` and different `pool` based on what to do.

```
jobs:

- job: Docker
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: Docker@2
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: 'MyContainerRegistry'
      repository: 'classificationapi'
      command: 'buildAndPush'
      Dockerfile: 'src/Services/Classification/ClassificationService.Api/Dockerfile'
      buildContext: ''

- job: Build
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  ...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#specify-stages